# How to turn FibSupplier into a generic FiniteSupplier?

Tags: java, generics, iterator, java-8, java-stream

Considering I have the following class:

```
public class Problem2 extends Problem<Integer> {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        result = toList(new FibSupplier(i -> (i <= 4_000_000)))
                .stream()
                .filter(i -> (i % 2 == 0))
                .mapToInt(i -> i)
                .sum();
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return "Problem 2";
    }

    private static <E> List<E> toList(final Iterator<E> iterator) {
        List<E> list = new ArrayList<>();
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            list.add(iterator.next());
        }
        return list;
    }

    private class FibSupplier implements Iterator<Integer> {
        private final IntPredicate hasNextPredicate;

        private int beforePrevious = 0;
        private int previous = 1;

        public FibSupplier(final IntPredicate hasNextPredicate) {
            this.hasNextPredicate = hasNextPredicate;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean hasNext() {
            return hasNextPredicate.test(previous);
        }

        @Override
        public Integer next() {
            int result = beforePrevious + previous;
            beforePrevious = previous;
            previous = result;
            return result;
        }
    } 
}
```

If you take a look at `FibSupplier` you can see that it exposes a generalized problem, even though it has a specialized implementation here, what I've managed to extract are:

- It has a `Predicate`.
- It has initial variables.
- It has a variable that needs to be tested by the predicate.
- It has a custom `next()` method.

My attempt to generalize this was with the following, note that I use a generic version for now instead of a specialized integer version:

```
public class FiniteSupplier<E> implements Iterator<E> {
    private final Predicate<E> predicate;

    public FiniteSupplier(final Predicate<E> predicate) {
        this.predicate = predicate;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasNext() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
    }

    @Override
    public E next() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
    }  
}
```

I want to be able to call `FiniteSupplier` with a `predicate`, however now I do not really know how to implement the other requirements I have managed to extract. I understand it could be done by extending the `FiniteSupplier` and making it abstract, but is that the correct way to do it?

Comment: I don't understand the meaning of generalized and specialized in this context. I'm afraid I can't really get an idea of the question.

Comment: Why do you need a predicate at all? I'd expect a `FibSupplier` to just *permanently* return `true` from `hasNext`...

Comment: @JonSkeet I want to be able to stop the supply under a certain condition, other than the absolute count of supplied integers, hence why I'd want the predicate. If there's any other way to wrap this up, then please suggest.

Comment: @RohitJain I meant that the general problem would be that I am trying to create a finite supplier, and the specialized version here is a finite supplier that supplies fibonacci numbers.

Comment: @skiwi: You should think about this in terms of composition. The Fibonacci sequence is infinite, but it's *generally useful* to be able to apply a predicate and only yield items while that predicate is true. (In .NET this is the TakeWhile method.) So build a *separate* stream which can compose any other stream and apply a predicate to each item, stopping when the next item fails to match the predicate.

Comment: @JonSkeet Okay, I think I understand it, one other small question: Is the implementation of `Iterator<E>` -> `List<E>` -> `Stream<E>` the best available one for a 'complex' supplier, no Fibonacci is not that complex for real, but involves a few variables, or is there a better way to do it?

Comment: @skiwi: I wouldn't go via a list at all, to be honest - but I haven't looked at the stream support in Java 8 in enough detail to know the idiomatic way of approaching it.

Answer (score 0):

The method `test(int/Integer)` can be used as `Predicate<Integer>` and as `IntPredicate`. The compiler does the conversion:

```
IntPredicate ip = (i) -> i>0;
Predicate<Integer> pi = (i) -> i>0;
Predicate<Integer> ip2pi = ip::test;
IntPredicate pi2ip = pi::test;
```

But you can't cast the two types as they are not assignable. IntPredicate does not extend Predicate.

So just use ::test when you create FibSupplier:

```
new FibSupplier(p) => new FibSupplier(p::test)
```

Or do that in a constructor. I'd introduce a new abstract type FiniteIntSupplier with an extra constructor that takes an IntSupplier and converts it to a general Supplier:

```
public FiniteIntSupplier(IntPredicate p) {
  this(p::test);
}
```